# table has no column name

Tags: android, mysql

public class DBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
public static final String TABLE_EVENT = "event";
public static final String EVENT_ID= "_id";
public static final String EVENT_NAME = "name";
public static final String EVENT_DATE = "date";
public static final String EVENT_DESCRIPTION ="description";

static final String DB_NAME = "DBEVENT";
static final int DB_VERSION = 1;


private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EVENT + " (" +
        EVENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        EVENT_NAME + " text not null, " +
        EVENT_DATE + " text not null, "+
        EVENT_DESCRIPTION + " text not null "+
        " )";



public DBhelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null,DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_EVENT);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

```
11-14 14:06:47.938  12123-12123/com.example.myacademicdiary E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) table event has no column named date
11-14 14:06:47.938  12123-12123/com.example.myacademicdiary E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting date= name= description=
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table event has no column named date (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO event(date,name,description) VALUES (?,?,?)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
            at com.example.myacademicdiaryfyp.event.SQLControler.insertEvent(SQLControler.java:34)
            at com.example.myacademicdiaryfyp.event.AddEvent.onClick(AddEvent.java:44)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: If you've added the date column after having run the app, you'll need to delete the database so it can re-create with the new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table event has no column named date (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO event(date,name,description) VALUES (?,?,?)
> ```

The above error tells, there's no column named `date` in table `event`. Most probably you have added a new column `date` later.

You've two option now to solve this issue.

1. Increment your database version as soon as you change your table structure.

   ```
   static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
   ```
2. Uninstall and reinstall the app again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.